# Change movement of a instantiated GameObject from next instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, game-development, gameobject

I'm using Unity and C#.

In my game, enemies are instantiated repeatedly and move towards the player in linear path. I want to make the movement of enemy in sine wave after some specific time has elapsed, to make game tougher.

The movement changes instantly, but I want the change to come in effect from instantiation of new(next) enemy and not to the ones currently present.

What can I do?

`EnemySpawner` script -

```
private void Start()
{
    timeelapsed = 0f;
    StartCoroutine(SpawnEnemies(delay));
}
private void Update()
{
    timeelapsed += Time.deltaTime;
}
private IEnumerator SpawnEnemies(float delay)
{
    while (true)
    {
        SpawnNewEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
private void SpawnNewEnemy()
{
    if (!enemyclone)
    {
        enemyclone = Instantiate(enemy, enemySpawner.transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

`Enemy Movement` Script:

```
private void Update()
{
    t = Time.time;
    if (EnemySpawner.timeelapsed > 0f && EnemySpawner.timeelapsed <= 20f)
    {
        enemy.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (EnemySpawner.timeelapsed > 20f && EnemySpawner.timeelapsed <= 40f)
    {
        enemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * 5 + Vector3.left * 3 * Mathf.Sin(10f * t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider perhaps assigning movement abilities for e.g. [A* path finding in unity](https://arongranberg.com/astar/) or [the original guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a thousand ways to accomplish this, but one I think might be easy to implement and understand might be to set up Action that is fired when you instantiate a new enemy from the spawner. I've quickly written up a few changes to your EnemySpawner and EnemyMovement scripts that I think might help you.

First, EnemySpawner:

```
public static event Action EnemySpawning;
void SpawnNewEnemy ( )
{
    if ( !enemyclone )
    {
        EnemySpawning?.Invoke ( );
        enemyclone = Instantiate ( enemy, enemySpawner.transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity );
    }
}
```

Now, the EnemyMovement:

```
private bool travelInLinearPath = true;

private void OnEnable ( )
{
    EnemySpawner.EnemySpawning -= OnEnemySpawning;
    EnemySpawner.EnemySpawning += OnEnemySpawning;
    travelInLinearPath = true;
}

public void OnEnemySpawning( )
{
    EnemySpawner.EnemySpawning-= OnEnemySpawning;
    travelInLinearPath = false;
}

private void Update ( )
{
    if ( travelInLinearPath )
        enemy.transform.Translate ( Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime );
    else
        enemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ( ).velocity = Vector3.forward * 5 + Vector3.left * 3 * Mathf.Sin ( 10f * Time.time );
}
```

Every time you enable an enemy, you're asking to be notified when the NEXT enemy is about to be spawned. When this happens, you tell THIS enemy to change from linear, to sinusoidal movement (`travelInLinearPath`). You also ask that this enemy not be notified anymore when a new enemy is spawned (unless you re-enable this enemy).

I've also not gone into whether you should be grabbing a new enemy from a pool of enemy objects. But the hope that you do is why I added the removal and re-enrolling in the event in `OnEnable()`. You might want/need to place that code within `Start()` instead depending on your enemy instantiation and creation later in the game.

Comment: I did everything as you said but as soon as the timer reaches 20f ,enemy stops moving. kindly note 1.I still have timeelapsed conditions in if statement 2.Im using C# 4 ,so i had to use if staements instead of EnemySpawning?.Invoke ( ); . Can any of these cause the problem.

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using? If you're using Unity 2017+, you can (and should) set your framework version to .Net 4.x. I read on the Unity site that using .Net Standard is actually encouraged for maximum portability, as well as a smaller build size. Then Invoke? will work correctly. Could you also explain if the code I supplied is incorrect, or you'd like it to do something it's not currently doing.

Comment: I switched to Net 4.6 now. The problem still persists,as the time reaches 20f (the time at which i want to make the change),the enemies stops to move

Comment: The enemy stops moving if the if conditions are not removed,but if i remove the if conditions and write code exactly as you have written,the enemy change the movement instantly as i have having in the first place

Comment: I'm a little confused now. You have a timer in your example, but you also say you want the movement to change when the new enemy is spawned. Do you want the timer in there, or do you want the movement to change when a new enemy is spawned?

Comment: I want the change to take place after the timer reaches some specific time,but the change should shouldn't appear in the enemies in scene,but to the enemies which get spawned next after the timer has reached that specific time

Comment: Oh, you're talking about enemy "Waves"... In that case, this answer is incorrect. I'd have to supply a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing now that the request was for "waves" of enemies, we need to add the wave defining items to each enemy. Therefore, modifying first the `EnemyMovement` script:

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum MovementType
    {
        None = 0,
        Linear = 1,
        Sinusoidal = 2
        // etc, etcc
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Movement affects the movement type of the enemy.
    /// </summary>
    public MovementType Movement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This affects the Speed of the Enemy. Used in conunction with Movement to
    /// produce the enenmy's wave movement type.
    /// </summary>
    public float Speed { get; set; }

    private Rigidbody rigidBody;


    private void Awake ( )
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ( );
    }


    private void Update ( )
    {
        switch ( Movement)
        {
            case MovementType.Linear:
                transform.Translate ( Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime );
                break;
            case MovementType.Sinusoidal:
                // You probably want the Speed property to affect this as well...
                rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.forward * 5 + Vector3.left * 3 * Mathf.Sin ( 10f * Time.time );
                break;

           // Any extra movement types you want here...
        }

    }
}
```

And then the `EnemySpawner` script to drive the Enemy instantiation:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Delay;
    public float StartSpeed;

    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject enemySpawner;
    public Vector3 offset;

    private float timeElapsed;
    private float currentSpeed;
    private EnemyMovement.MovementType currentMovement;


    void Start ( )
    {
        timeElapsed = 0f;
        currentSpeed = StartSpeed;
        StartCoroutine ( SpawnEnemies ( Delay ) );
        currentMovement = EnemyMovement.MovementType.Linear;
    }


    void Update ( )
    {
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

        // We can determine at what time the Wave parameters change here.
        if ( timeElapsed >= 40.0f )
        {
            currentSpeed += 10.0f; // Add speed, for example.
        }
        else if ( timeElapsed >= 20.0f )
        {
            currentMovement = EnemyMovement.MovementType.Sinusoidal;
        }
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnEnemies ( float delay )
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            var enemyClone = Instantiate ( enemy, enemySpawner.transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity );
            var movement = enemyClone.GetComponent<EnemyMovement> ( );

            // We now set what the enemy uses as the Wave values.
            movement.Speed = currentSpeed;
            movement.Movement = currentMovement;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds ( delay );
        }
    }
}
```